# In HTML E-Mail, I can't go next line

Tags: asp.net, email

I have funny problem in showing my emails in my boxes. As i send emails via my host ,it sends to my users successfully but in some part of my email text i want to go to the next line and i used 
 tag to do that. the wieard thing is that in some mailboxes it go to the next line and in some others it doesn't go! for example the correct form is:

```
Dear Dr smith:
nice....

thank you very much
```

but it shows like this:

```
Dear Dr smith: nice.... thank you very much
```

here is my code:

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
StringBuilder bodyMsg = new StringBuilder();
msg.Subject = "Submission Confirmation";

bodyMsg.Append("<html><head><img src=" + "http://javahery21.ir/images/header.jpg" + ">" + "<title>CONFIRMATION EMAIL:</title></head><body>");
bodyMsg.Append("<br/>");
string link = string.Format("http://javahery21.ir/Activate.aspx?userID={0}", userID.ToString());
bodyMsg.Append("Dear " + RadioButtonList_Prefix.SelectedItem.Text + " " + name.Text + " " + middle.Text + " " + lastname.Text + ":<br/> Thank you for registering with Publishing manuscript submission system.");
bodyMsg.Append("To confirm and complete your registration<p>" + " <a href=" + link + ">" + "fallow this link" + "</a></p>.");
//bodyMsg.Append("<br/><br/>");

bodyMsg.Append("<br/>This link is active for 48 hours. If the link is not visited within this time frame, your registration will be discarded and you will need to register again.<br/><br/></br>Best regards,</br>Publishing<br/>http://***.com");

msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
msg.Body = bodyMsg.ToString();

msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;

//  msg.ReplyTo = new MailAddress(TextBox2.Text);
msg.From = new MailAddress("***@***.**");
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(TextBox_email.Text));
SmtpClient mailsender = new SmtpClient();

mailsender.Host = "SmtpClient.***.**";

mailsender.Port = 587;
mailsender.EnableSsl = true;
mailsender.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("****@***.**", "classaspnet");

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
//Literal1.Text = "<script>alert(' ')</script>";
smtp.Send(msg);
```

where did i make a mistake?
can any body help me?

Comment: save your html and view in browser , check whether break is coming or not

Comment: it works fine in browser!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `<p>` tag.

Eg.

```
<p>Dear Dr smith:</p>
<p>nice....</p>
<br/>
<p>thank you very much</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed out this

```
String msgText = getHtmlMessageText(...);
msg.setContent(msgText, "text/html");
```

You didnt set the content type for the message

Comment: thank you for answering, does it has special name space? because getHtmlMessageText and setContent can not be identified by visual studio.